# REPEAT function equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how to achieve the same functionality as REPEAT() in SQL*Plus. For example consider this problem: display the character '*' as many times as the value specified by an integer attribute specified for each entry in a given table.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Nitpicking: SQL*Plus doesn't have any feature for that. The **database server** (Oracle) provides the ability to execute SQL and has such a function:

You are looking for `rpad()`

```
select rpad('*', 10, '*')
from dual;
```

will output

```
**********
```

More details can be found in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions159.htm#SQLRF06103

Comment: the funny thing is selecting 10 characters takes much longer than selecting 20k characters using this

Answer (score 9):

For single characters, the accepted answer works fine.

However, If you have multiple characters in a given string, you need to use `RPAD` along with `length` function like this.

```
WITH t (str) AS
  ( 
   SELECT 'a'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 'abc'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT '123'
   FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT '#+-'
   FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT RPAD(str, 5*LENGTH(str), str) repeated_5_times
FROM t;
```

**Output**:

```
REPEATED_5_TIMES
---------------
aaaaa
abcabcabcabcabc
123123123123123
#+-#+-#+-#+-#+-
```