# regex to convert alphanumeric and special characters in a string to * in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a requirement to convert all the characters in my string to `*`. My string can also contain special characters as well.

For Example:
`abc_d$` should be converted to `******`.

Can any body help me with `regex` like this in `oracle`.

Thanks

Comment: What shouldn't be converted?

Comment: @user7294900, Every character should be converted to *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REPEAT function equivalent in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884233/repeat-function-equivalent-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and replace any single character (`.`) with `*`.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE (col, '.', '*')
FROM yourTable
```

### Demo

Comment: regex? why not rpad? or repeat?

Comment: @PatrickArtner If you could benchmark both of our answers, it would be interesting.

Comment: Tim - I did benchmark the two solutions. As expected, the regexp solution takes (much) longer. What was unexpected was **how much** longer - 20 times as long!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex you could also use

```
select rpad('*', length('abc_d$ s'),'*') from dual  
-- use '*' and pad it until length fits with other *
```

Doku: [rpad(string,length,appendWhat)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_rpad)

Repeat with a string of '*' should work as well: [repeat(string,count)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_repeat) (not tested)

regex or rpad makes no difference - they are optimized down to the same execution plan:

n-th try of rpad:

```
 Plan Hash Value  : 1388734953 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation        | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|  1 |   FAST DUAL      |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

n-th try of regex_replace

 Plan Hash Value  : 1388734953 

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation        | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
|  1 |   FAST DUAL      |      |    1 |       |    2 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it does not matter wich u use.

Comment: A regex based option is somewhat more flexible, e.g. if the OP's requirements change then a regex might be more adaptable.

Comment: I would not expect any `select` list function to affect the execution plan, but as regexes tend to be resource-intensive it would be interesting to see whether `rpad` gave significantly better performance.

Comment: From a quick test on my laptop with Oracle 12.1.0.1.0, the `rpad/length` version is a few hundredths of a second faster than the `regexp_replace` version for 10,000 30-character strings. That may not be significant for most use cases, but you never know.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson How did you measure that? Just curious - I have no oracle here and rely on sqlfiddle for testing. I was sold on the "more flexible" and with same execution plans I would have though them to be "equal"?

Comment: @PatrickArtner - I just ran the two versions (with `select ... from dual connect by rownum <= 100000` to generate a bigger row set) a few times each in PL/SQL Developer and noted the typical times. Not very scientific. Execution plans reflect things like join order and access paths, not the internal workings of functions.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER**

As suggested by Tom Biegeleisen’s brother Tim, I ran a test to compare a solution based on regular expressions to one using just standard string functions. (Specifically, Tim's answer with regular expressions vs. Patrick Artner's solution using just LENGTH and RPAD.)

Details of the test are shown below.

**CONCLUSION**: On a table with 5 million rows, each consisting of one string of length 30 (in a single column), the regular expression query runs in 21 seconds. The query using LENGTH and RPAD runs in **one second**. Both solutions read all the data from the table; the only difference is the function used in the SELECT clause. As noted already, both queries have the same execution plan, AND the same estimated cost - because the cost does not take into account differences in function calculation time.

**Setup**:

```
create table tbl ( str varchar2(30) );
insert into tbl
  select a.str
  from   ( select dbms_random.string('p', 30) as str
           from   dual
           connect by level <= 100
         ) a
         cross join
         ( select level
           from   dual
           connect by level <= 50000
         ) b
;
commit;
```

Note that there are only 100 distinct values, and each is repeated 50,000 times for a total of 5 million values. We know the values are repeated; Oracle **doesn't know that**. It will really do "the same thing" 5 million times, it won't just do it 100 times and then simply copy the results; it's not that smart. This is something that would be known only by seeing the actual stored data, it's not known to Oracle beforehand, so it can't "prepare" for such shortcuts.

**Queries**:

The two queries - note that I didn't want to send 5 million rows to screen, nor did I want to populate another table with the "masked" values (and muddy the waters with the time it takes to INSERT the results into another table); rather, I compute all the new strings and take the MAX. Again, in this test all "new" strings are equal to each other - they are all strings of 30 asterisks - but there is no way for Oracle to know that. It really has to compute all 5 million new strings and take the max over them all.

```
select max(new_str)
from   ( select regexp_replace(str, '.', '*' ) as new_str
         from   tbl
       )
;

select max(new_str)
from   ( select rpad('*', length(str), '*') as new_str
         from   tbl
       )
;
```

Comment: Tom Biegeleisen is my brother.  I am _Tim_ Biegeleisen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE('B^%2',
                 '*([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]|[ ]|([^A-Z]|[^a-z]|[^0-9]|[^ ]))', '*') "REGEXP_REPLACE"
  FROM DUAL;
```

I have included for white spaces too

Comment: Hi Garima, You are answer is also correct. But @Tim answer also covers white space.

Comment: too complicated. '.' matches any character

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,lpad(regexp_replace(name,name,'*'),length(name),'*')
from customer;
```

Comment: confusing much? what are you doing here?  you replace the whole string by one * using regexp_replace and then padding it out to the former length? How is that an improvement over mines or Tim Biegeleisens solution? You dont get double benefits from using both methods - its just slower